# How to validate date duration between Start_date and End_date

Tags: php

```
 In the database table 



 Cinema_id   |    Start_date | End_date        
    1        | 20/12/2016    | 30/12/2016 
    1        | 01/01/2017    | 31/01/2017
```

I want to validate not to duplicated duration. eg when user insert start_date 22/01/2017 to 02/02/2017, i want to show "9 days are already in use". If your input the duration already in database, show validate errors.

Comment: try this library [Carbon Date Difference](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference). This will ease the things with dates

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
    $sd='20/12/2016';
    $ed='30/12/2016'; 
    $datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($sd)));
    $datetime2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($ed)));
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: User have to input start and end date and i have to check multiple start and end date from db that not between already in db..thankq..

Answer (score 0):

Use inbuilt php class DateTime with diff function

```
$date1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('01/01/2017')));
$date2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('31/01/2017')));
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
$difftime = $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

There is another way also

```
$sdate = strtotime('2017-01-01');
$edate = strtotime('2017-01-31');

$days = ceil(abs($edate - $sdate) / 86400);
```